# Задача на js. Функция создающая селект на странице

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, столкнулся с затруднением. У меня есть функция, которая создаёт селект на веб странице, на входе она принимает массив объектов и строку.
Мне необходимо делать так, чтобы функция создания выпадающего списка могла обрабатывать не только массив объектов, но и другие виды входящих значений, например массив примитивных значений типа string или number или объект с произвольными свойствами и значениями типа string или number

```
let arr = [
  {
    value: "Value one",
    label: "Value one"
  },
  {
    value: "Value two",
    label: "Value two"
  },
  {
    value: "Value three",
    label: "Value three"
  }
]

let arr2 = ['a','b','c']

function createSelect(arr, str) {
  const body = document.body;
  const select = body.appendChild(document.createElement('select'));

  arr.forEach(function(a) {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = a.value;
    option.innerHTML = a.label;

    select.appendChild(option)
    if (option.value = str) {
      option.setAttribute('selected', true);
    }
  });

  if (typeof arr[value] == 'string' || 'number') {
    arr.value = 'value four';
  } else {
    return arr;
  }


  return select
}


createSelect(arr2, "value")
```

Comment: К сути вопроса не относится, но тем не менее: у вас опечатка — вместо `if (option.value = str)` вы, наверное, имели в виду `if (option.value === str)`

Comment: И такие конструкции будут делать не то, что вам нужно: `typeof arr[value] == 'string' || 'number'` — правильнее будет `typeof arr[value] == 'string' || typeof arr[value] == 'number'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, вам нужно что-то вроде этого:

```js
let arr2 = ['a','b','c'];

function createSelect(arr, str) {
  if (typeof arr[0] === 'string') {
    arr = arr.map(str => ({ value: str, label: str }));
  } else if (typeof arr[0] === 'number') {
    arr = arr.map(num => ({ value: String(num), label: String(num) }));
  }

  const body = document.body;
  const select = body.appendChild(document.createElement('select'));

  arr.forEach(function(a) {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = a.value;
    option.innerHTML = a.label;

    select.appendChild(option);
    if (option.value === str) {
      option.setAttribute('selected', true);
    }
  });
  
  return select
}

createSelect(arr2, "b");
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь